# Switcher<Placeholder, PlaceholderSwitcher>.GetStack returns null How to implement dynamic placeholders in sitecore

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I'm trying to implement Nick Wesselman's Dynamic Place Holder technique in Sitecore. I'm using sitecore 6.5 and asp.net.

http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2011/August/Dynamic_Placeholder_Keys_Prototype
http://www.techphoria414.com/Blog/2012/May/Sitecore_Page_Editor_Unleashed

I used the sourcecode I Found in the Sitecore_Page_Editor_Unleashed BLOG

All the pipelines seem to be in place and working. But in the Dynamic Placeholder control the following bit of code returns 0 (zero) although there are five dynamic placeholders on the control

```
Stack<Placeholder> stack = Switcher<Placeholder, PlaceholderSwitcher>.GetStack(false);
```

To Isolate the problem I created a very simple sitecore instance. 1 layout and 1 sublayout.

In the codebehind sublayout I have the following code for demo purposes:

```
var list = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    list.Add(i);
}

Repeater.DataSource = list;
DataBind();
```

This is the source of the ascx/sublayout

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater">
     <ItemTemplate>
       <mi:DynamicKeyPlaceholder runat="server"  ID="pl" Key="place"></mi:DynamicKeyPlaceholder> 
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Result is that all five placeholders still have the same key.

What to do?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tested this solution with multiple dynamically created placeholder controls inside the same sublayout. It's designed to solve the problem of the same sublayout (with a placeholder) being placed on a page, multiple times. It works by grabbing the ID of the containing rendering and appending it to the placeholder key. Steps I would take:

- Ensure that the sublayout containing your repeater is placed in the layout dynamically, through a placeholder. You should not be using `<sc:Sublayout/>` to put the sublayout on the page. This may explain why the stack is empty.
- You will also need to databind the "Key" field on the `DynamicKeyPlaceholder`. Within the same sublayout, all the `DynamicKeyPlaceholder` controls need to have a unique Key.

Of course, the danger here is that if the data driving your repeater changes, the Key could change. You might consider re-evaluating your architecture and driving it based on placing the same sublayout multiple times (with datasources), instead of a repeater.

Comment: So you where right. I had to change my design. The thing is that the dynamic placeholder actualy has to be added to a containing placehoder via the Page Editor. By saving this the dynamicplace holder will be saved to the database. Only then Stack<Placeholder> stack = Switcher<Placeholder, PlaceholderSwitcher>.GetStack(false); will be able to get the stack. So in code dynamicly adding placeholders will not work because they are not be saved by sitecore. It was tricky to change my design and not loose functionality in my app. But now everything works like a breeze. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cool can you either post and accept your own answer, or accept mine?  Thanks Paul.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is similar what you are requesting...I created a reference of another sublayout (which implements dynamic placeholders) from the calling control (which want to have dynamic ph).

So suppose my calling control is ControlA and implementing control is ControlB.

This is the **markup of ControlA**:

```
 <ControlB ID="SectionItems" runat="server" CurrentItem="<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
```

And this is the **code behind** for it:

```
 private static void SetIndexForControlBItems(RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
   {
       var controlBItems = e.Item.FindControl("ControlB") as ControlB;
       if (controlBItems != null)
          controlBItems.PropertyName = e.Item.ItemIndex.ToString();
   }
```

When you assign the property name (which is going to be present in ControlB) then you will get the value of which index you are assigning dynamic PH to. And in **ControlB** you can do something like this:

```
 private void SetPlaceholderKeys(RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Placeholder phPreColumnContentTopLeft = e.Item.FindControl("phColumnContentTopLeft") as Placeholder;
        if (phPreColumnContentTopLeft != null)
            phPreColumnContentTopLeft.Key = "topLeftColumnSectionItems" + e.Item.ItemIndex + PropertyName;
```

Hope this *helps*!

Comment: Thank you. I Already fixed the problem in the initial way. But this could work as wel.

Comment: Not a problem! Glad I could be of any help.